# Digestive-functors and listOf

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, digestive-functors

I've been able to use [digestive-functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors-0.8.0.0) with simple forms successfully in a snap application; however, I'm getting stuck when trying to handle a list of hidden inputs. There is something I'm not quite getting on how to use `listOf`. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

The rendered html from a previous page includes the following hidden fields:

```
<div id='messageForm.recipients' class='inputList'>
  <input type='hidden' name='messageForm.recipients.indices' value='0' />
  <input type='hidden' id='messageForm.recipients.-1.email' name='messageForm.recipients.-1.email' value />
  <input type='hidden' id='messageForm.recipients.0.email' name='messageForm.recipients.0.email' value='emai1l@email.com' /> 
  <input type='hidden' id='messageForm.recipients.1.email' name='messageForm.recipients.1.email' value='email2@email.com' /> 
</div>
```

The data types are:

```
data ConfirmMessage = ConfirmMessage {
  isoDate :: T.Text,
  subject :: T.Text,
  body    :: T.Text,
  action  :: T.Text,
  recipients :: [Recipient]
} deriving (Show) 

data Recipient = Recipient {
  email :: T.Text 
} deriving (Show)
```

The forms are:

```
messageForm :: (Monad m) => Form T.Text m ConfirmMessage
messageForm = ConfirmMessage
  <$> "isoDate"    .: stringRead "Missing ISOdate" Nothing
  <*> "subject"    .: stringRead "Subject required" Nothing
  <*> "body"       .: stringRead "Body required" Nothing
  <*> "action"     .: stringRead "Missing action" Nothing
  <*> "recipients" .: listOf recipientForm' Nothing

recipientForm' :: (Monad m) => Formlet T.Text m Recipient
recipientForm'= Recipient
  <$> "email"      .: text Nothing
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
Couldn't match type `Text.Digestive.Form.Internal.FormTree
                       m0 v0 m0 Recipient'
              with `Maybe Recipient -> Form T.Text m Recipient'
Expected type: Formlet T.Text m Recipient
  Actual type: Text.Digestive.Form.Internal.FormTree
                 m0 v0 m0 Recipient
Relevant bindings include
  recipientForm' :: Formlet T.Text m Recipient
    (bound at src/Handler/TradeNotifyConfirm.hs:191:1)
In the expression: Recipient <$> "email" .: text Nothing
In an equation for `recipientForm'':
    recipientForm' = Recipient <$> "email" .: text Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay **disclaimer**: I have never used `digestive-functors`, but here is how I approach this kind of problem:

1) Your error message says `Expected type: Formlet T.Text m Recipient` and `Actual type: Text.Digestive.Form.Internal.FormTree m0 v0 m0 Recipient`

2) Look at the documentation and see that:

```
type Formlet v m a = Maybe a -> Form v m a 
type Form v m a = FormTree m v m a
```

so we expand the **expected** from above to get:

```
Formlet T.Text m Recipient 
-- v ~ T.Text, a ~ Recipient
Maybe Recipient -> Form T.Text m Recipient
--
Maybe Recipient -> FormTree m T.Text m Recipient
```

now look again:

- Expected type: `Maybe Recipient -> FormTree m T.Text m Recipient`
- Actual type: `FormTree m0 v0 m0 Recipient`

We are missing a `Maybe Recipient`! From what I see above I guess you want to just ignore that argument and therefore we have:

```
recipientForm' :: (Monad m) => Formlet T.Text m Recipient
recipientForm' _ = Recipient <$> "email" .: text Nothing
```

which compiles just fine, yay :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks... the approach on expanding the expected types was very helpful.